# Adding a value to a Map value with Before Update

Tags: trigger, map

I am still learning to develop so thank you in advance for your help!

I have used the Lightweight Trigger Framework from Chris Adlridge. [Seen here](http://chrisaldridge.com/triggers/lightweight-apex-trigger-framework/)

The objective is to make a checkbox True if one of a couple of fields is empty / null in a  Before Update meothd. The error message I receive is that it is read-only so I think I am trying to update the oldItems:
*"RecipeTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Collection is read-only External entry point External entry point Class.TriggerDispatcher.Run: line 22, column 1 Trigger.RecipeTrigger: line 3, column 1"*

I need help with updating the existing record. Thanks!

Here is my code for the method (I do have some other attempted I tried commented out):

```
    public static void BeforeUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
       
       List<Recipe__c> beforeUpdateRecipeList = newItems.values();
      // Map<Id,Application> appMap=new MapMap<Id,Application>([select id,Status from Application]);

    
for (Recipe__c beforeUpdateRecipe : beforeUpdateRecipeList)  { 
            SObject oldRecipe = oldItems.get(beforeUpdateRecipe.Id);
            
          
      //  for(Recipe__c beforeUpdateRecipe : beforeUpdateRecipeList)
      //  {
            if (
                (String.isBlank(beforeUpdateRecipe.Name))
                ||
                (beforeUpdateRecipe.Active_Time__c == NULL)
                ||
                (beforeUpdateRecipe.Active_Time_Units__c == NULL)
                ||
                (beforeUpdateRecipe.Servings__c == NULL)
            )
            {    
           newItems.get(oldRecipe.Id).beforeUpdateRecipe(Draft__c) = TRUE;
             // beforeUpdateRecipe.Draft__c = TRUE;
            newItems.put(oldRecipe.Id,beforeUpdateRecipe);
               // beforeUpdateRecipe.Draft__c = TRUE;
               // beforeUpdateRecipeList.add(beforeUpdateRecipe);
                
            } else {
                // is false, do nothing
            }
        }// end for
        Update beforeUpdateRecipeList;
        
    }//end BeforeUpdate Method
```

Answer (score 0):

In a before update trigger, you don't need to call a DML operation to update the record that is already being updated; this happens automatically simply by setting a field value on the record. Further, you can't modify Trigger.new, Trigger.old, Trigger.newMap, or Trigger.oldMap by adding or removing records (this includes put, remove, and clear methods). This line should work:

```
beforeUpdateRecipe.Draft__c = true;
```

You may have been thrown off by other errors; this was most likely because the DML statement was failing. Again, you don't need it during a before insert/before update trigger.

Final word of caution, your query to Application__c is unfiltered, and will eventually cause problems. You will need to do some additional work to limit it just to the records you need to query.